# Downloading .tgz file and extracting it to different path in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tar

How to download a .tgz file and then extract it to a different directory in Dockerfile. Following the best practices for Dockerfile mentioned at https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/, I have tried something like:

`RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/things && curl -O https://example.com/big.tgz | tar -xvzf big.tgz -C /usr/src/things`

When trying to build docker image, i see following error:

`tar (child): big.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now tar: Child returned status 2 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `f` flag from the `tar` command, like this:

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/things && curl -O https://example.com/big.tgz | tar -xvz -C /usr/src/things
```

The output from `curl` is being piped to `tar` instead of being written to a file, but `tar -f` will look for a non-existent file `big.tgz`.

See the options for `-f, --file=ARCHIVE: Use archive file or device ARCHIVE`

Source: [tar manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html)